# Is there a way to hide my VPS provider info on whois site / geolocation info?

Tags: proxy, vps, squid

I am looking to sell proxies on a VPS but I am wondering if there's a way to mask the ip so that they cannot tell which provider I am using. Not sure if this makes sense.

Currently my proxies show my vps provider's name on iplocation.net.

Comment: Yes, use private IP addresses.

Comment: The proxy users traffic has to leave at some point, which means your VPS IP will be in logs, even if the entry point to your proxy is on another provider or CDN.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, and it always will.

What you ask is like hiding the area prefix from your phone number - how are people supposed to call you?

Means: They have to know your IP adress. The IP Address belongs to an AS (Automonomous System) and in order to be reachable those are published - with all the connections between them. And if the VPS provider is a real provider (not just one server) he has gotten the IP Addresses from whatever allocation organization they are from (tehre are a small number on this planet managing the IP address pools for the continents). And guess what - that database is also public.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KX5jNnDMfxA